# Parsing a string containing day of the week into date in R

Tags: r, date

I have a set of dates represented as strings that have the following format:

```
dates_strings = c("Monday 27 March 2017", "Friday 24 March 2017" , "Wednesday 22 March 2017", "Monday 20 March 2017" , "Wednesday 15 March 2017")
```

My aim is to parse these strings into `date` format. I have tried `anytime()` and something like `as.Date(dates_strings, format = "%A% %d %m %Y")`. I wonder whether there is a [lubridate](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html)-type solution similar to `dmy()` that would consider the day of the week as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "%B" for the month name and not "%m"

```
dates_strings = c("Monday 27 March 2017", "Friday 24 March 2017" , "Wednesday 22 March 2017", "Monday 20 March 2017" , "Wednesday 15 March 2017")

as.Date(dates_strings, format = "%A %d %B %Y")
[1] "2017-03-27" "2017-03-24" "2017-03-22" "2017-03-20" "2017-03-15"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
as.Date(dates_strings, "%a %d %B %Y")
#[1] "2017-03-27" "2017-03-24" "2017-03-22" "2017-03-20" "2017-03-15"
```